# Why is access vba throwing sub or function not defined when attempting to read a recordset field?

Tags: vba, ms-access

As the title says, I get an error "Sub or Function Not Defined" when the code tries to compile.  It breaks on the RS_Logistics![Received].  That field does exist in the recordset which is verified by looking at the table IM_Logistics, and by checking the watch that I set on the object and confirming the Field Item "Received" exists.  It's a boolean field.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private ROID As Long
Private RS As Recordset
Private RS_PartDetail As Recordset
Private RS_Logistics As Recordset

Public Sub Load_ID(RepOrderID As Long)
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM IM_ReplenishmentOrders WHERE ReplenishmentOrderID = " & RepOrderID
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If RS.RecordCount > 0 Then
ROID = RepOrderID

strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MT_PartDetail Where MT_PartDetail_ID = " & RS!MT_PartDetail_ID
Set RS_PartDetail = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM IM_Logistics Where ReplenishmentOrderID = " & ROID
Set RS_Logistics = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Else
ROID = 0
End If
End Sub

Public Property Get ETA() As Date 'Derived from Logistics Records
On Error GoTo fail
RS_Logistics.MoveFirst
While Not RS_Logistics.EOF
If ((RS_Logistics![Received] = False) And Nz(ETA, DateAdd("Y", 10, today())) > RS_Logistics![Expected Date]) Then
ETA = RS_Logistics![Expected Date]
End If
RS_Logistics.MoveNext
Wend
fail:
End Property
```

I've been working with recordsets in this database for over a year.  No idea why this is popping up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message has nothing to do with recordset or its fields. "Sub or Function Not Defined" is because Today() is not an Access VBA function. Use Date().

Also, Access VBA DateAdd requires "yyyy" as year interval.

Comment: Thanks for this!  It would have been so nice if VBA would have indicated the "Today" function as it should have.  Hard to keep all these languages straight sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

2 suggestions to catch things like these easier:

- Set the "option explicit" on all your modules (and/ir in the preferences to save you doing it manually). This would have told you that today() is an undefined variable instead of looking for a sub/function by that name
- Learn to look out for today() remaining as today() and not being corrected to Today() which the editor would have done if Today() had been valid Sub/Function.

Comment: I do have option explicit set.  But that is probably the best piece of advice anyone coding in VBA can get, so I will not fault you for repeating it.